# What's the degree of freedom of this kind of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

We first have a unitary matrix in $\mathbb{C}$ 
$$U = \{a_{ij}\}_{n\times n},$$
where "unitary" means $$U'U = I, \quad U'\text{means conjugate transpose.} $$

I know how to calculate its degree of freedom, which is $n^2$ if we consider a real variable as one degree of freedom.
Now we have a matrix which is $$\{|a_{ij}|^2\},$$
I wonder how to calculate its degree of freedom.

Comment: as far as everything in this question is real, the same

Comment: @Arashium  I have edited this question. Does it match what you have in mind?

Comment: @Doris: The matrix is bistochastic so the degree of freedom is at most $(n-1)^2$. It seems to be exactly that. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistochastic_matrix